# TSQL Recursion from multiple sources

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, recursion

I have a query where I am looking up a user in our employee table and recursively going through the records to find out everyone that reports up to our source input.

My question is, instead of passing a single value, in the case below, `@QID` Id like to be able to pass multiple values. I tried to modify it to say `WHERE QID IN ('user1', 'user2')` but it always only returned the data for the first user it found in the `IN` clause

```
WITH empList(mgrQID, QID, NTID, FullName, lvl, countOfDirects)
AS
(
       SELECT TOP 1 mgrQID, QID, NTID, FirstName+' '+LastName, 0, CountOfDirects
       FROM dbo.EmployeeTable
       WHERE QID = @QID

       UNION ALL

       SELECT b.mgrQID, b.QID, b.NTID, b.FirstName+' '+b.LastName, lvl+1, b.countOfDirects
       FROM empList a
       CROSS APPLY dbo.Fetch_Directs_by_qid(a.QID)b
)
```

Comment: If you do a `WHERE QID IN ('user1', 'user2')` and leave `SELECT TOP 1` then the anchor query will return just one record. This single record is then the only input in the recursion chain.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of TOP 1 and do it like this. If you have repeat values, add a group by to your anchor query or DISTINCT

```
DECLARE @QID TABLE (val VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @QID VALUES ('user1'),('user2')

WITH empList(mgrQID, QID, NTID, FullName, lvl, countOfDirects)
AS
(
       SELECT mgrQID, QID, NTID, FirstName+' '+LastName, 0, CountOfDirects
       FROM dbo.EmployeeTable
       WHERE QID IN (SELECT * FROM @QID)

       UNION ALL

       SELECT b.mgrQID, b.QID, b.NTID, b.FirstName+' '+b.LastName, lvl+1, b.countOfDirects
       FROM empList a
       CROSS APPLY dbo.Fetch_Directs_by_qid(a.QID)b
)
```

Comment: Will this recursion run for each user prior to exiting the loop? For example, right after this I would have an insert query to put the data into a temp table. I want to prevent putting in duplicates if there were any. However, If I put a `DISTINCT` on the `Select` clause after the union, I don't know if it will catch them? Does that make any sense?

Comment: It's hard to tell because your using a function in cross apply and I don't know your data structure. BUT if you original query worked for 1 person, then this should work fine. I just mentioned you don't want to have duplicates in the first select statement because that will return duplicates as it will find the parent child of the same person multiple times. You probably don't have to worry about it. If you are unsure if this will work, load some values into a temp table and run my query. See if it works as planned.

Comment: Hmm okay; the cross apply is just getting all the people who report directly to the `QID` passed to it. The scenario that's playing out is if I select Bob who is a manager, and I also select Jim who is Bobs manager, its going to get me everyone that reports up to Bob AND everyone that reports up to Jim. In this cause its going to contain duplicates and I was just trying to see if there was a way to prevent that within the recursion it self. For example only get them if they do not already exist within the data set of this recursive function

Comment: The best way to deal with duplicates is probably to add a DISTINCT or GROUP BY when you query the CTE. Example: SELECT * FROM CTE GROUP BY columns